How to print with QZ Tray in React Project with Zebra Printer to print product lables?
I'm working on a React ERP of products and goods, here in a component I have a print button which I want to print product barcode, labels, name and other details with Zebra printer, I have made connection in my MacOS system with Zebra printer and its successfully connected and working fine.
How can I use qz tray api to print my labels in ReactJS Project, I've made a component  SmallLabelPrint.jsx where I designed how the label should look while print, but how to print that JSX component. Here is the code of label component:-
export default function SmallLabelPrint({data}) {
  const labelHtml = `
    <label style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
      <p>${data.name}</p>
      <p>${data.desc}</p>
    </label>
  `;

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: labelHtml }} />;
}

Now in the below Product component I have a button to print with the details of the product. And with the documentation of the QZ Tray I have added this code, the connection is fine but its not printing and throwing this error:-
//AddSRF.jsx

const printWithQZTray = async () => {
    try {
      // Connect to QZ Tray websocket
      await qz.websocket.connect();

      // Find the desired printer
      const printer = await qz.printers.find(printerName);
      const formatData = <SmallLabelPrint data={printData} />;
      const config = qz.configs.create(printerName, {
        size: { width: 4, height: 6 }, // Adjust size as needed
      });

      // Prepare the print data (replace with your content)
      const data = [
        "\nN\n", // New label command
        "q609\n", // Label format selection
        {
            type: "raw",
            flavor: "file", // Assuming text format
            data: formatData, // Use the generated string as data
            options: { language: "EPL" }, // Adjust language as needed
        },
        "\nP1,1\n", // Print command
    ];

      // Send the print job
      await qz.print(config, data);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error printing:", error);
      // Handle printing errors gracefully (e.g., display an error message to the user)
    }
  };

  const handlePrint = async () => {
    const formatData = <SmallLabelPrint data={printData} />;
    await printWithQZTray(formatData);
  };

//Jsx
<Button onClick={handlePrint}>Print</Button>

And with this getting this error:-

Maybe the code is wrong because I didn't find anything where it is working with React project, kindly help with this, Thanks in advance.

The QZ related error seems to stem from a string serialization issue when you construct your URL: https://localhost:5173/transactions/srf/[object%20Object], specifically [object%20Object] appears to be a bad URL constructed from something in JavaScript.

@tresf even if I add the correct route of the component added in App.js also, still throws the error. Error: Cannot parse (FILE)http://localhost:5173/transactions/srf/print/small-print into a raw COMMAND command: Error parsing data from FILE     at _qz.websocket.connection.onmessage  this is th error, and this router /transactions/srf/print/small-print is the router of my SmallLabelPrint.jsx

Can you start QZ Tray from command line and see what the full exception is?  https://qz.io/docs/faq#console-logs.  One common cause is that your controller may require authentication.  If this is the case, you could always fetch() it and append the contents using command or base64 instead of file.
